# I cannot make Svelte work with CSS for D3.js charts, despite having tried all options available

Tags: css, d3.js, sass, svelte

I'm new to Svelte, but not to D3. Can't make CSS work with Svelte and D3, no matter what I try.
I've created a new component called BarChart.svelte
It generates a Bar Chart, I want to colour the bars, but CSS will not recognise non-existing elements. I've researched and found several solutions, none of which work for me.

Here is the code for the BarChart.svelte
Please refer to the CSS area to see all options I have tried.

- Added SCSS pre-processor
- Used global
- Created a fake rect somewhere so that a previous element exists (seems like svelte is adding something else to keep under the right scope, or something like that).
- tried all CSS selector combinations I could think of.

So far the only thing that works is referring to the SVG tag. This is NOT what I want. I would like to be able to colour individual bars to stand them out and such I cannot rely solely on colouring anything under SVG.

Notes:

- I know SCSS is correctly configured as the fake rectangle that I put is coloured using it, however this does not apply to all rect items, as it would be expected.
- If that is removed, the rectangle becomes red.
- If I removed the red CSS line, then it becomes violet, and if I remove the violet it becomes green. It will completely ignore the CSS with global. If I get rid of the green, it will become black.

Here is a link to my repo. I am not sure if it's public.
https://bitbucket.org/vik000/dashboard/src/master/src/
In case it isn't, a data.js file is needed with the following content:

```
export default [
{
    "country": "Brazil",
    "titles": 5
},
{
    "country" : "Germany",
    "titles" : 4
},
{
    "country" : "Italy",
    "titles" : 4
},
{
    "country" : "Argentina",
    "titles" : 2
},
{
    "country" : "Uruguay",
    "titles" : 2
},
{
    "country" : "France",
    "titles" : 2
},
{
    "country" : "England",
    "titles" : 1
},
{
    "country" : "Spain",
    "titles" : 1
}
```

]

[image]

```
<script>
export let data;
export let name = 'barChart';
// export let name;
// name = !name ? 'barChart' : name

import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { scaleLinear, scaleBand } from 'd3-scale';
import { extent, max } from 'd3-array';
import { axisBottom, axisLeft } from 'd3-axis';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import { each, element } from 'svelte/internal';

console.log(data);

const width = 800
const height = 600
const margin = {
    left: 60,
    right:10,
    top: 10, 
    bottom: 60
}

onMount(() => {
    const maxTitles = max(data.map(d => d.titles))
    let y = scaleLinear().domain([0, maxTitles]).range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
    let x = scaleBand().domain(data.map(d => d.country)).range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]).padding(0.1)
    
    let xAxis = axisBottom().scale(x)
    let yAxis = axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(maxTitles)

    select("#xAxisGroup").call(xAxis)
    select("#yAxisGroup").call(yAxis)

    let elements = select("#elementGroup").selectAll("rect.bar").data(data)
    elements.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", d => x(d.country))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.titles))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", d => height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y(d.titles))
})
```

```
<svg id={name} height={height} width={width}>
    <rect class="bar" x=50  y=10 width=100 height=10></rect>
    <g id="elementGroup" transform="translate({margin.left}, {margin.top})">
    </g>
    <g id="axisGroup">
        <g id="xAxisGroup" transform="translate({margin.left}, {height - margin.bottom})"></g>
        <g id="yAxisGroup" transform="translate({margin.left}, {margin.top})"></g> 
    </g>
</svg>

<style lang="scss">
    // using SASS
    svg {
        fill: green; // not what I want
        rect.bar {
            fill: grey !important; 
        }
    }

    svg rect {
        fill: violet;
    }

    rect.bar :global(svg){
        fill: cadetblue;
    }
    rect.bar {
        fill: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I think you are using `:global` wrong, probably should be `svg :global(rect.bar)` instead

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Not sure I fully understand the documentation.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks @StephaneVanraes !